# Comparing versions with git and Araxis on Mac

Tags: git, macos, araxis

I'm trying to use Araxis Merge to diff two branches of my git repo.  When using git difftool, it opens each file one at a time (including a lot of libraries I don't need to worry about).  When using hg, I get a nice folder view from the command line.  I found this SO topic:

[using araxis merge for folder comparison on git branches (OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717917/using-araxis-merge-for-folder-comparison-on-git-branches-osx)

but when I follow the instructions (including on the Araxis Merge docs), I get this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not supported (0x8000002D)
```

I also tried to get the "Versions" menu drop-down to work: here (https://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/plugin-git under the section "PREPARING MERGE TO USE THE PLUGIN") it states "tested with Git for Windows."

I'm using Araxis Professional Edition v2016.4774

Has anyone gotten this to work on Mac?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh I finally found a solution, in case others are ever looking.  The trick is to use the --dir-diff option on the git command line, like this:

```
git difftool --dir-diff aBranchName..anotherBranchName
```

Found it here: [use Winmerge inside of Git to file diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881594/use-winmerge-inside-of-git-to-file-diff/1884517#1884517)

This opens Araxis in folder comparison view.  Still can't open a Folder Comparison with git version from within Araxis Merge though...